# Struggling to make a twitter bot post automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I created a javascript bot (using twiw npm) intended to make a post every day. I can make make it post, but can't seem to make it post on any kind of schedule except very quickly (10 seconds or 5 minutes). I tried using setInterval for this purpose:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Twit = require("twit");
const T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         process.env.API_KEY,
    consumer_secret:      process.env.API_SKEY,
    access_token:         process.env.TOKEN,
    access_token_secret:  process.env.SECRET_TOKEN,
});

const tweetContent1 = [
 array content removed
];

 const tweetContent2 = [
 array content removed
];

const randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tweetContent1.length));
const randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tweetContent2.length));

const tweetContent = tweetContent1[randomNumber1] + tweetContent2[randomNumber2];

setInterval(function(){

  T.post("statuses/update", { status: tweetContent
 }, function(err, data, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
  console.log(data);
}});

}, 86400000);


console.log('Your bot is running, go catch it.');
```

It works in my own terminal (with the interval set to something a bit smaller) and the code works without the surround setInterval.

I then uploaded this version to Heroku, where it seemed to try to post the same thing again and again (137 error on Twitter's API). I then tried Glitch where it worked with a smaller interval but trying to use a cron job to wake it up didn't work.

Is there another way to make this bot post on schedule, e.g. every day at a certain time?

Comment: I have experience with heroku and this kind of program with very long setInterval will not work there, unless you have a paid account. Try waking the program with a third party site

Comment: Hi, I've tried using cron-job to wake it on Heroku but this fails. I'm now thinking this is because it doesn't generate anything at the Heroku address, only on Twitter, hence cron-job failing on both Glitch and Heroku. I tried deploying a version without the setInterval around the function, but  with the same result.

Im now wondering whether it's my interaction with Heroku that's the issue i.e. maybe i need to use 'worker' rather than 'web' and use Heroku's scheduler.

Comment: wrap it around an express app

Comment: Thanks ariel, once I added express and gave it something to display (res.send) it now works on Heroku and cron-job is waking it.

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to ariel who commented on the OP - Turns out I needed to add express to the code so that it wouldn't crash when the app was accessed via a URL i.e. using Cron Job and the like to wake the app.

The code is now:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const Twit = require("twit");

const app = express();

const T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         process.env.API_KEY,
    consumer_secret:      process.env.API_SKEY,
    access_token:         process.env.TOKEN,
    access_token_secret:  process.env.SECRET_TOKEN,
});

const tweetContent1 = [
 *array content*
];

 const tweetContent2 = [
 *array content*
];

const randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tweetContent1.length));
const randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (tweetContent2.length));

const tweetContent = tweetContent1[randomNumber1] + tweetContent2[randomNumber2];

T.post("statuses/update", { status: tweetContent
 }, function(err, data, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
  console.log(data);
}});

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("Should have worked mate.");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log("Your bot is running, go catch it");
});
```

Comment: Hi @Badgersmack, I understand the overall idea, but where did you run the cron-job that makes the request to `/` and wakes up the Heroku server?

Comment: Hi @juanocho, I'm using cron-job.org